# Opening a call intent and an SMS intent without the need for manifest permissions

Tags: android, permissions

recent android has restrict the applications that can use CALL_PHONE and SEND_SMS permissions in android

My app need to use it in it is main logic, is there anyway to do that in old devices without manifest permissions?

Comment: Use `ACTION_DIAL` (with a `tel:` `Uri`) and `ACTION_SENDTO` (with an `smsto:` `Uri`). Neither require any permissions.

Comment: ok will try it and get back to you

Comment: @CommonsWare it works, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for call phone

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + yourphonenumber));
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

for sms

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address","your address");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","your body");
```